# Adding border to bootstrap theme (CSS) doesnt work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, border

I want to add a regular shadow to my `img` and when I use the following code, everything works fine:

```css
img.img-border {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123,129,140,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123,129,140,1);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123,129,140,1); }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="img-border" src="https://placeholdit.co/i/200x150">
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I do the same within a bootstrap theme, just nothing happens with the `img`. Does anybody have an idea? This is the bootstrap section code:

```
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
    <section class="pb16">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row v-align-children">
                 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 mb-xs-24">
                     <h3 class="large mb40 mb-xs-16">TITLE BLABLA</h3>

                     <p class="lead" style="text-align: justify">Text Content blablabla</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-filled btn-lg mb32 mt-xs-40" href="#">Click Here</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 text-center" >
            <img class="img-shadow" alt="Screenshot" src="img/picture.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--end of row-->
        </div>
        <!--end of container-->
    </section>
```

This is in custom.css:

```
  html.body.img.img-shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123,129,140,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123,129,140,1);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123,129,140,1);
  }
```

Comment: Post the HTML and css for the entire page.

Comment: Its too big, I can post a chunk of it. One more thing: I also could add border shadow to the `nav`, but I did it directly without a class, because there is only one `nav`.

Comment: Yeah, post the relevant chunk.

Comment: If you post your code into Bootply your `box-shadow` is being honored w/o issue ( https://www.bootply.com/Ewt33B2Vv0 ). This suggests something other than Bootstrap is interfering, or that your CSS isn't loading correctly.

Comment: in addidtion to the bootstrap-theme are you loading the boostrap css as well?

Comment: Yes, I am loading it. Unfortunately no luck. I have now tried everything everybody has suggested, but the only thing which work is inline styling. This is very bad practice, but I am just going with it for now. Thanks anyway

Comment: No, that's not the only thing left. Please understand that without seeing the actual code in your case, all we can do is guess around. But as you have seen, guesswork is not a good basis for troubleshooting. If you can make available the EXACT code that causes the trouble, I **will** fix the issue. Guaranteed!

Answer (score 1):

In order to override Bootstrap css, your custom css must have the same or higher specificity AND your custom css must be loaded **after** you load Bootstrap css.

In your updated code you posted that you are using this for the css rule:

`html.body.img.img-shadow`

Change it to this instead: `.img-shadow`

Comment: It is loaded after the bootstrap.css BUT I dont know what else to do to have a higher specifity

Comment: You posted that you are using this for the css rule: `html.body.img.img-shadow` that won't do anything. Change it to this: `.img-shadow` and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Load your CSS styles **after** the bootstrap version and make a custom class and apply that to overcome specificity issues.

[read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

```css
.custom {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123, 129, 140, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123, 129, 140, 1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123, 129, 140, 1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<div class="well">
the well is proof that the bootstrap is loading
  <img class="img-border custom" src="https://placeholdit.co/i/200x150">
</div>
```

Comment: It is already loaded after the bootstrap, also it is already a custom class for `img`

Comment: the code above is working with bootstrap, so there may be some other issue with your code that is not included in this post

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your CSS isn't specific enough to overwrite the Bootstrap CSS.

Try adding some of the parent classes/ elements in front of the image tag and see if that works.

e.g.

```
html body img.img-border {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123,129,140,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123,129,140,1);
     box-shadow: 10px 10px 41px -12px rgba(123,129,140,1); 
}
```

You could also force the style on with !important at the end but that is bad practice so only use it when absolutely necessary.

Comment: In that case try adding `!important` before each semi colon

if that makes it work then you know its a css specificity issue. if not then you have another issue.

also in the code you put above you have put `html.body` before your other css class which is incorrect. It needs to be `html body` to show that html is the parent element.

What you have put there is only applying css if your html tag also has the class body

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. I have now tried everything everybody has suggested, but the only thing which work is inline styling. This is very bad practice, but I am just going with it for now. Thanks anyway

Comment: sorry i couldnt help